# How to autocomplete path and file in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script, where I want to read a path and a file with autocompletion. I used `[read -e -p "path name:" pathname]`. This works fine, but when I try `[read -e -p $pathname filename]`, the file autocompletion just doesn't work. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't work?

Comment: Are you sure that `$pathname` is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

The file autocompletion works from the current directory. If you want it to work in a given directory, you have to change the current directory to it:

```
read -e -p "path name:" pathname
cd $pathname
read -e -p $pathname filename
```